# Achieve smart matching dropdown in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text and a dropown menu.
I would like to match the text with the dropdown menu in jquery.
My Dropdown

```
<select>
<option value="1">First name</option>
<option value="2">Last Name</option>
<option value="3">Address</option>
</select>
```

for example
if my text contains lname i want the first option in dropdown to be Last Name.How can i do this in jquery?

Comment: Do you want your option to be Selected or want to shift option text to first position?

Comment: i want it to be selected

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
   $('#MySelect option')
        .filter(function() { return $.trim( $(this).text() ) == txt; })
        .attr('selected',true);
```

[Demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qYRr7/)